# How to avoid anonymous methods in "dynamic" event subscription?

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods

How could I refactor the method

```
private void ListenToPropertyChangedEvent(INotifyPropertyChanged source,
                                          string propertyName)
{
    source.PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == propertyName)
            MyMagicMethod();
    };
}
```

if I wished to avoid using the anonymous method here?

Comment: The trick here is not the anonymous method -- it is *the closure* that is used. The only other way that comes to mind is creating a new object which implements a `PropertyName` variable/property or similar as well as an `OnPropertyChanged` event handler and wiring that up and ... ick.

Comment: @pst: Thanks for the comment. I guess I am still a little fuzzy about the internals here. Reading http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx now. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the closure that is implicitly created by the lambda explicitly:

```
private void ListenToPropertyChangedEvent(INotifyPropertyChanged source,
                                          string propertyName)
{
    var listener = new MyPropertyChangedListener(propertyName);
    source.PropertyChanged += listener.Handle;
}

class MyPropertyChangedListener
{
    private readonly string propertyName;

    public MyPropertyChangedListener(string propertyName)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public void Handle(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == this.propertyName)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what my lambda above really means internally? Interesting. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by having a single event handler for all instances that uses a dictionary of instances that you are following:

```
private Dictionary<INotifyPropertyChanged, List<string>> sourceMap =
    new Dictionary<INotifyPropertyChanged, List<string>>();

private void ListenToPropertyChangedEvent(INotifyPropertyChanged source,
                                            string propertyName)
{
    if (sourceMap.ContainsKey(source))
        sourceMap[source].Add(propertyName);
    else
    {
        source.PropertyChanged += source_PropertyChanged;
        sourceMap[source] = new List<string> { propertyName };
    }
}

void source_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var source = sender as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    var list = sourceMap[source];
    if (list.Contains(e.PropertyName))
        MyMagicMethod();
}
```

This version doesn't have any error checking or removal but it demonstrates the technique.  It is particularly valuable if you **listen for multiple properties from the same source**.  This is because it only adds a single handler to the `PropertyChanged` event per instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed I might listen for multiple properties from the same source. There may be a little more bookkeeping involved with this approach, since I don't want to keep the sources from being garbage collected by being referenced in the dictionary, but that can be managed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what youre trying to achieve or why you dont want to use anonymous methods, but you could do something more generic:

```
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler GetHandler
      (Func<PropertyChangedEventArgs, bool> test, Action toInvoke)
    {
        return new PropertyChangedEventHandler(
            (o, e) => 
            {
               if (test(e))
                toInvoke(); 
            }); 
    }
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
  source.PropertyChanged += GetHandler                
            (
                p => p.PropertyName == propertyName, MyMagicMethod
            );
```

That way your if test and the target method group can be swapped about easily. Your event handler is also strongly typed rather than anonymous.

Comment: My co-workers are not comfortable with anonymous methods, so I try to avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: Technically a PropertyChangedEventHandler is a delegate specifically intended for listening to events that propagate PropertyChangedEventArgs, so anytime you use a strongly-typed EventHandler such as that you are avoiding the use of an anonymous method, provided that you just pass in a method group, which is a function (minus parentheses, bc you arent invoking it immediately) you want to call when the event fires. I wouldn't say its necessary to create an entirely new class that encapsulates event listening - thats what an EventHandler already does.