# How to get the parameters passed to the asynchronous method in the callback (not lambda)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the parameters passed to the asynchronous method in the callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554380/how-to-get-the-parameters-passed-to-the-asynchronous-method-in-the-callback)

I need convert this lambda to method callback

```
var sendRegistrationDelegate =
    new AsyncSendRegistrationDelegate(AsyncSendRegistrationMethod);

sendRegistrationDelegate.BeginInvoke(registrationToUser, label, ar =>
{
    var responceFromServer = sendRegistrationDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);

    if (responceFromServer.IsError)
    {
        SetText(label, registrationToUser.Name + @" " +
            responceFromServer.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        SetText(label, registrationToUser.Name + @" " +
            responceFromServer.Data);
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516528

Comment: @Dark Falcon, I want to make individually CALLBACK method.

Comment: @dtb, I not understand answer for this questions.

Comment: You're question is not making any sense. Try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have a grasp on lambdas and anonymous delegates?

In this snippet:

```
    sendRegistrationDelegate.BeginInvoke(registrationToUser, label, ar =>
    // start of method
    {
        var responceFromServer = sendRegistrationDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);

        if (responceFromServer.IsError)
        {
            SetText(label, registrationToUser.Name + @" " +
                responceFromServer.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            SetText(label, registrationToUser.Name + @" " +
                responceFromServer.Data);
        }
    }
   // end of method
     , null);
```

...the opening and closing `{  }` mark the beginning and ending of a method, like so:

```
void AsyncCallbackMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // method body
}
```

Your BeginInvoke method would look like:

```
sendRegistrationDelegate.BeginInvoke(registrationToUser, label, new AsyncCallback(AsyncCallbackMethod), null);
```